# MIPS Floating Point fahrenheit to celsius

Tags: floating-point, mips

```
        .text
        .globl main
main:
        la $a0,prompt   # print prompt on terminal
        li $v0,4
        syscall

        li $v0,5        # syscall 5 reads an integer
        syscall

        mul $t0,$v0,9   # to convert,multiply by 9,
        div $t0,$t0,5   # divide by 5,then
        add $t0,$t0,32  # add 32

        la $a0,ans1     # print string before result
        li $v0,4
        syscall

        move $a0,$t0    # print  result
        li $v0,1
        syscall

        la $a0,endl     # system call to print
        li $v0,4        # out a newline
        syscall

        li $v0,10
        syscall         

        .data
prompt: .asciiz "Enter temperature (Celsius): "
ans1:   .asciiz "The temperature in Fahrenheit is "
endl:   .asciiz "\n"
```

Assembly language is hard! How can i change this code to make it floating point and not just integer? Need to be able to type in celsius temp like 23.4 and get a decimal answer.

Comment: _"How can i change this code to make it floating point"_. By using the [MIPS floating-point instructions](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/secondyear/spim/node20.html). You can read more about individual instructions in _MIPS32™ Architecture For Programmers
Volume II: The MIPS32™ Instruction Set_.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution for your problem

```
.data
inputText: .asciiz "Fahrenheit: "
outputText: .asciiz "Celsius: "
delta: .float 32.0
scalar: .float 5.0
another_scalar: .float 9.0

.text
li $v0, 4
la $a0, inputText
syscall

li $v0, 6
syscall

l.s $f1, delta
l.s $f2, scalar
l.s $f3, another_scalar

sub.s $f0, $f0, $f1
mul.s $f0, $f0, $f2
div.s $f0, $f0, $f3

li $v0, 4
la $a0, outputText
syscall

li $v0, 2
mov.s $f12, $f0
syscall

li $v0, 10
syscall
```